# DataSource creation for MongoDB in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to create a DataSource implementation for MongoDB in java like in java.sql.DataSource is it possible to implement such thing in MongoDB? if so can anyone give me some tips or clues how can i achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you use an existing one? For example, see http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a datasource for MongoDB it has on already created in its API.

```
public static MongoClient mongoClient;
public static DB db;
public static DBCollection collection;

public static void setupDB() throws UnknownHostException {
    mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", port);

    db = mongoClient.getDB("Your Database");

    collection = db.getCollection("Collection Name");

}
```

This will connect you to the database and save the client connection. Whenever you need to call something from the collection that you are using just use.

```
collection.(command here)
```

Depending on your version of the MongoDB driver depends on if you need the username and password for the database.If you would like to use authentication just see this link: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/

Or find a newer update of their reference